# Magento Recurring Profiles with non-Paypal payment method

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, subscription

Interested to know if (a) this is possible, and (b) whether any of you have successfully implemented the functionality. The [wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles) repeatedly refers to "Currently, by default, Magento supports purchasing items with recurring profiles only for the PayPal payment system and only through the Express Checkout method." - I'm not sure if that's because there are no payment other methods currently implementing the Interface, or because they've hardcoded the architecture such that it will only work with Paypal.

To test this, I've created a payment method that stubs out the `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface` methods, and that payment option is now presented when I go through checkout with a Nominal product (i.e. product with a recurring profile) and the order is placed successfully.  However it doesn't appear in the list of Sales>Recurring Profiles or Customer's Billing Agreements.  I guess they will be populated by the stubbed-out methods.

I suspect that the fields in `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile` are setup to mirror those required by Paypal, so it may take some mapping to translate those into another payment gateway's requirements, but that should be achievable theoretically, possibly using a model override.

Sorry for the rambling question, but I'm keen to hear your experiences since the framework seems to support it on first investigation.

Comment: Did you ever find other payment gateway to use for recurring payments?

Answer (score 1):

Which country are you in? With some adaption of the RBS WorldPay module you can use RBS FuturePay which is geared around repeat payments. I only had to use the module to take two 50-50 payments, however, the FuturePay technical support was brilliant and the Phoenix WorldPay module is not bad either (as starting points go). Getting it to integrate into Magento's Recurring Payments profile is not something I needed to get to work, however, you could put some other form for people to cancel an order.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mathew. I have a payment gateway already specified by the client who manage the subscription side of things.  I specifically would like to use Recurring Profiles since the Customer and Admin views of the subscriptions are already built-out.